# Can't switch system on / off in Expression Engine 2.9

Tags: system

I am on EE 2.9 and I can’t switch the system on / off anymore.

When I go to Admin -> General Configuration and set “Is the system on?” to “No”, nothing changes.

I’ve already tried this in various browsers, cleared all browser and EE caches but to no avail.

I’ve also followed the steps suggested by Anna in this thread: [System Offline problems](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/system-offline-problems)

What else could I try?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: After you save the configuration and reload the page does your setting persist, or is it back to "Yes"?

Comment: Do you have Dev Demons Smart Switch installed? This has got me once before. http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/smart_switch

Comment: Is your config.php file writeable?

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be obvious. But it's not because you are logged in is it? If you make sure you log out after turning the system off, refresh your browser and then see if the site is visible.

Comment: No, it's not because I am logged in. I tried it with multiple browsers and also cleared their caches multiple times.